# Custom cart price on Add to Cart action

Tags: event-observer

I am Trying to add **custom price on add to cart for product**. It worked successfully but on shopping cart page - currency change stopped working. It just change currency symbol. Price conversation doesn't work. Below is used raw code.

```
$item->setCustomPrice($params['final_price']); <br/>
$item->setOriginalCustomPrice($finalPrice); <br/>
$item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
```

Above code is added in `""checkout_cart_product_add_after""` event.

Comment: Above code is added in ""checkout_cart_product_add_after"" event.